# Django, scraping: What's the best way to detect "changes" while scraping?

Tags: python, django, web-scraping

This is not typical **code** problem, instead, it's a design problem I'm facing right now.

---

Let's say I do have a webpage *(which is not mine)*, and I'd like to scrape a few pieces of information. Most important information, for me, would be **when** (datetime) character **logged in**, and **when he logged off**, but I collect other information as well. **Login** is known from point **2**(see below), but **logout** i have to calculate
I can access 2 pages:

1. http://**x**/online.php - It gives me list of **online** nicknames (200 - 500 entries)
2. http://**x**/character.php?name=**nickname** - it gives me details of each nickname like: Character name, Guild, Sex, Level, Class (Vocation), Status (offline/online), Last login.

---

I make only 2 "operations" in tasks.py which are:

- **A** - **update_or_create** using information from point "2"
- **B** - **Get online list** - using information from point "1"

---

So, how it works now is (each minute, thanks to Celery, I do this):

- Set transaction autocommit to False
- Do A for characters, that have **login** registry, but does not have **logout** **(From database point they are still "online")**
- If at this point character's status is "OFFLINE", add database entry to **logout** as datetime.now
- Do A for characters from list B
- Commit & Set transaction autocommit to True

---

And the problem is, that I'm unsure if that's good idea.
My **models.py**: (Comments are just to clarify what I'm doing)

```
class Guild:
     name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Player(models.Model):
    #FK:
    guild =  models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True) # Does he have guild?
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True) 
    sex = models.CharField(choices=SEX_CHOICES, max_length=7) # Male / Female
    level = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField() 
    vocation = models.CharField(choices=VOCATION_CHOICES, max_length=50) # His class
    status = models.CharField(choices=ONLINE_CHOICES, max_length=10) # Offline / Online
    lastlogin = models.DateTimeField() 

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Deaths(models.Model):
    text = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    killed = models.ForeignKey(Player, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='killed') # Who got killed
    killer = models.ForeignKey(Player, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='killer') # Who killed him

    date = models.DateTimeField() # When he died?
    level = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField() # On which level player died
    pvp = models.BooleanField() # Death was due to PvP or PvE?

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('date',)


class OnlineDetails(models.Model):
    player = models.ForeignKey(Player, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    login = models.DateTimeField() # When he logged in
    logout = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True) # When he logged off

    def __str__(self):
        return self.player.name + " " + str(self.logout) if self.logout else self.player.name

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('logout', 'login')
```

it works, but I was wondering if it's **best** way to do so. Actually, I think that this way it's bad, because I have to scan over ~500 characters in one minute which makes it hard with "antyddos" shield.

Do you have any better solution or technology I should pick up?
I'm not best in python nor django, still learning.

Comment: Did you check if the website provides an API endpoint? If you check 500 entries a minute they will block you at some point...

Comment: They do not provide API for sure.

Comment: Since the page inst your there is no easy and performatic way to do that... so you will have to heck the pages response (if the url chances) and some iconical tags and classes, if your crawler dont find things in that struct it is probabily changed.

Comment: As more being especific is easier to detect chances, but is kinda hard check the entire page to get what really changed or not

Comment: Maybe... just maybe... you can get the entire HTML page and compare it... but dont looks good

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure you can measure the whole process, how long it takes and so on but I think updating ~500 entries takes few millisecs. Bigger problem could be the scraping of 500 entries every minute, that means you have to send them about ~8 requests per second (based on point 2. not point 1.). I think you are scraping point 1. every minute and on change you scrape the missing characters. Point 1 is notp roblem at all. Parsing so many pages could be hard but not impossible. Also I suggest you to download the pages and store them for some period of time if anything fails during the process also it's faster to download the pages and in other thread parse them parallely, because the most time difficult is sending the request and downloading the response. To the transaction autocommit... it could be problem in multithreaded envinment. You should try measuring the process with and without it if it is worth the risk of not knowing what is happening.